# Apply vba to multiple cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that can generate page number on cells. 
But I want it apply to mutiple cells in one time instead of single cells.

```
Sub pagenumber()

'updateby Extendoffice 20160506

    Dim xVPC As Integer
    Dim xHPC As Integer
    Dim xVPB As VPageBreak
    Dim xHPB As HPageBreak
    Dim xNumPage As Integer
    xHPC = 1
    xVPC = 1
    If ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Order = xlDownThenOver Then
        xHPC = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count + 1
    Else
        xVPC = ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks.Count + 1
    End If
    xNumPage = 1
    For Each xVPB In ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks
        If xVPB.Location.Column > ActiveCell.Column Then Exit For
        xNumPage = xNumPage + xHPC
    Next
    For Each xHPB In ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks
        If xHPB.Location.Row > ActiveCell.Row Then Exit For
        xNumPage = xNumPage + xVPC
    Next
    ActiveCell = "Page " & xNumPage & " of " & Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.DOCUMENT(50)")
End Sub
```

What can i do for this? Is it also possible for apply the code to highlighted cells?

Answer (score 1):

At the end write this:

```
Range("A1:B10")="Page "&xNumPage&" of "& Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.DOCUMENT(50)")
```

Instead of:

```
 ActiveCell = "Page "&xNumPage& " of " & Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.DOCUMENT(50)")
```

Making sure that `Range("A1:B10")` is the range to which you want to apply the numbers.

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: it is not working, if I apply the code in page one, to cell a1:a250,
it will appear page 1 of 6 even it is in page 2